# What does Spiegelhalter's normality test do?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, residuals, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

What's exactly the null-hypothesis of this test?

Does it test for having a normal distribution with specified parameters or just generally?

I've searched it on the internet, but I haven't found anything about the hypotheses. I want to use it for analyzing residuals in linear regression.

Comment: Why this particular test?

Comment: It was suggested on this website when the variance is unknown and because of small sample data.

Comment: If you have very little data, then maybe you shouldn't be testing for normality. The power of tests is so weak, that it's pointless. Why do you need to test for normality?

Comment: Too many points fall out of prediction interval so the assistant told me to test the normality of residuals and correlation.

Comment: Why not start with the popular tests such as Jarque Bera or Lilleifors?

Comment: @Dorotea do you mean the test in Spiegelhalter, D.J., 1977, A test for normality against symmetric alternatives. Biometrika, 64, {415–418}; OR the test in Spiegelhalter, D.J., 1980, An omnibus test for normality for small samples. Biometrika, 67, 493–496. I had thought you meant the 1977 test but on reflection I expect you probably mean the 1980 one.

Comment: @Glen_b For small samples, but I'm not sure whether the spiegelhalter test for normality in 'normtest' R package includes that one or the other. I cannot conclude it from the given documentation.

Comment: @Aksakal I thought I had to have specified parameters for those tests. I just want to know what hypotheses exactly are tested with this test. I realize I should have gone with other tests, but now it doesn't matter anymore. It was for a project for my statistics course.

Comment: @Dorotea Thanks for the details. That particular R function explicitly mentions the statistic from the 1977 paper in its help (and indeed mentions the 1977 paper in the Description: "`Performs Spiegelhalter test for the composite hypothesis of normality, see Spiegelhalter (1977).`") -- no matter, I wrote answers for both tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spiegelhalter's (1977) test is a test for general normality (i.e. unspecified parameters) against symmetric alternatives. To my recollection it performs fairly well against a number of symmetric alternatives for small to moderate samples.

Spiegelhalter's (1980) test is a test for normality (again with unspecified parameters) against both symmetric and asymmetric alternatives.

Both these tests start out as attempts to combine most powerful location- and scale-invariant
tests for normality against specific alternatives.

The 1977 test combines a test for normality vs uniform and normality vs double exponential alternatives, but due to difficulty obtaining the distribution of the mean deviation from the median he substitutes the mean deviation from the mean (which is asymptotically equivalent), resulting in a combination of two pre-existing tests for normality.

The 1980 test combines tests for normality vs uniform and normality vs double exponential alternatives with tests for exponential and flipped exponential alternatives. Spiegelhalter reports good power for $n\leq 20$ for the 1980 test.

Another good test against a wide range of alternatives that doesn't specify parameters is the Shapiro-Wilk test.

However, if you're assessing normality because it's an assumption for some other procedure (like tests of regression parameters), formal hypothesis tests are usually misguided - they don't answer the right question (and often lead people to worry more when it matters less while in small samples a non-rejection should offer little comfort, since power will be low).

Spiegelhalter, D.J., 1977, A test for normality against symmetric alternatives. Biometrika, **64**, p415–418.

Spiegelhalter, D.J., 1980, An omnibus test for normality for small samples. Biometrika, **67**, p493–496.